# Android Studio: The device already has an application with the same package but a different signature

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk, apk-expansion-files

I have an app, which I also have in the Google Playstore. I built this app on an old machine at the time and signed it there as well. Since I need to update the app, I pulled the code from my repo to my new machine (different Android Studio version). Likewise, I had saved the key for the signature and copied it to my new machine. I can also build the app with the signature. However, when updating on the phone, it keeps crashing. Android Studio tells me the following when I do this:

**The device already has an application with the same package but a different signature.**

The key, as I said, is actually the same for the siganture
How can I fix this? The app is used by multiple users through the playstore.

But I also need to have the possibility to update the app only via the APK (so not only from the store).

Comment: Go to your play console, visit your app, then Setup -> App integrity, this page describes how Google Play App Signing works. In brief, the key you use is not the same as the Google Play Store use.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, I don't get the "problem" if I upload the APK in Google Play Console and update the app from there? I tested it in an "internal test" and get the same error :/